# req.body returning undefined with 200 response

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

Stuck trying to get a simple registration form working. Getting a 200 ok response from Chrome console but a console.log is returning 'undefined' when calling on any of the form fields from the post request.

Anticipated behaviour is a redirect to the logged in 'home' but instead I am being thrown validation errors, assuming because the data is disappearing somewhere.

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var expressValidator = require('express-validator');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var multer = require('multer');
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var db = mongoose.connection;

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

//Handle file updates
var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' });

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

//Handle session middleware from express
app.use(session({
  secret: 'secret',
  saveUninitialized: true,
  resave: true
}));

//passport
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

//Validation
app.use(expressValidator({
  errorFormatter: function(param, msg, value) {
      var namespace = param.split('.'),
      root    = namespace.shift(),
      formParam = root;

    while(namespace.length) {
      formParam += '[' + namespace.shift() + ']';
    }
    return {
      param : formParam,
      msg   : msg,
      value : value
    };
  }
}));

// Use flash
app.use(flash());
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.locals.messages = require('express-messages')(req, res);
  next();
});


app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});


module.exports = app;
```

user.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var User = require('../models/user.model');

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send('respond with a resource');
});

router.get('/register', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('register',{
    'title': 'Register'
  });
});

router.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('login',{
    'title': 'Login'
  });
});

router.post('/register', function(req, res, next){
    // Get Form Values
    var name = req.body.name;
    var email = req.body.email;
    var username = req.body.username;
    var password = req.body.password;
    var password2 = req.body.password2;

    // Check for Image Field
    if(req.body.profileimage){
        console.log('Uploading File...');

        // File Info
        var profileImageOriginalName    = req.files.profileimage.originalname;
        var profileImageName            = req.files.profileimage.name;
        var profileImageMime            = req.files.profileimage.mimetype;
        var profileImagePath            = req.files.profileimage.path;
        var profileImageExt             = req.files.profileimage.extension;
        var profileImageSize            = req.files.profileimage.size;
    } else {
        // Set a Default Image
        var profileImageName = 'noimage.png';
    }

    // Form Validation
    req.checkBody('name','Name field is required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('email','Email field is required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('email','Email not valid').isEmail();
    req.checkBody('username','Username field is required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('password','Password field is required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('password2','Passwords do not match').equals(req.body.password);

    // Check for errors
    var errors = req.validationErrors();

    if(errors){
        res.render('register',{
            errors: errors,
            name: name,
            email: email,
            username: username,
            password: password,
            password2: password2
        });
    } else {
        var newUser = new User({
            name: name,
            email: email,
            username: username,
            password: password,
            profileimage: profileImageName
        });

            // Create User
    User.createUser(newUser, function(err, user){
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(user);
    });


        // Success Message
        req.flash('success','You are now registered and may log in');

        res.location('/');
        res.redirect('/');
    }
});


module.exports = router;
```

register.jade

```
extends layout

block content
    h1 Register
    p Please register using the form below
    ul.errors
        if errors
            each error, i in errors
                li.alert.alert-danger #{error.msg}
    form(method='post',action='/users/register',enctype='multipart/form-data')
        .form-group
            label Name
            input.form-control(name='name', type='text',placeholder='Enter Name')
        .form-group
            label Email
            input.form-control(name='email', type='email',placeholder='Enter Email')
        .form-group
            label Username
            input.form-control(name='username', type='text',placeholder='Username')
        .form-group
            label Password
            input.form-control(name='password', type='password',placeholder='Enter Password')
        .form-group
            label Confirm Password
            input.form-control(name='password2', type='password',placeholder='Confirm Password')
        .form-group
            label Profile Image
            input.form-control(name='profileimage', type='file')
        input.btn.btn-default(name='submit', type='submit',value='register')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try commenting out `app.use(bodyParser.json());` in your app.js . The request body is not a json in this case.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. I've got it running now. See the update. Unsure why calling on multer makes it work.

Answer (score 0):

Added users.js:

```
var multer = require('multer');
var upload = multer({dest: '../uploads/'});
```

And updated the POST call:

```
router.post('/register',upload.single('profileimage'),function(req, res, next)
```

Does anyone know why this would make it work now?